# Questions on Forces involved in oscillating mass dipole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, dipole

Say we have two balls of radius $R$ on both sides of a massless dielectric rod and it starts oscillating due to an external electric field. Other than the external field would there be an electric field caused by one of the masses on the other one, and since the charged masses are moving would there be a magnetic field caused by it as well. If so, how exactly do we calculate this and how would this affect the torque and force involved in the dipole from the classical result of $p\times\vec{E}$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the charges will act on each other with additional forces. It is possible to calculate them for prescribed motion. In general, the mutual interaction will result in shift of effective inertial mass (negative for system with negative electric potential energy) and in radiation damping (as energy is radiated away by the oscillating dipole, the mutual retarded forces will slow the oscillator down).

If you want to calculate these forces in detail, you are in for a months/years of studies. Besides EM textbooks, you can look here to see what theory and approximations are involved in these kinds of calculations:

J. L. Synge, *On the electromagnetic two–body problem.*, Proc. Roy. Soc. A 177 118–39 (1940)

https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rspa.1940.0114

Comment: Assuming there is no gravity and friction/damping forces (which leads to some nasty results as seen) what would be involved?

Comment: The damping force arises as part of the mutual EM forces. Those forces can be calculated as Lorentz forced of individual EM fields of the particles. Those EM fields can be determined only if some additional assumptions are made about past motion and state of the fields. The simplest possibility is that the fields are retarded solutions of the Maxwell equations. Search for Jefimenko equations.